# VBA Dir function with wildcard matches wrong file

Tags: vba, directory, wildcard

I will preface this by saying that I have found a workaround, but I am asking here to try and understand what is happening.

I'm searching a folder for the existence of a file. The folder contains plenty of files, all with unique 3 digit suffixes.

The files are titled something like "123 2020_quarter_3_report_1234.xlsx"

**The problem:**

I have a function called fileExists, which runs Dir() and returns true/false if any results.

I have a loop where I am looking for files like so;

```
for each suffix in suffixArr
    if fileExists("P:\ath\to\file\" & suffix & "*.xlsx") Then
          #do stuff with suffix
    end if
loop
```

I'm having a problem however with suffix number 696.

There is no "**696** 2020_quarter_3_report_1234.xlsx", however the Dir keeps returning true.

The file that it's finding and returning true on is "**669** 2020_quarter_3_report_1234.xlsx"

Note: that final "1234" is another unique number, and the one on 669's file contains no 6s or 9s.

**The workaround:**

```
for each suffix in suffixArr
    if fileExists("P:\ath\to\file\" & suffix & " *.xlsx") Then
          #do stuff with suffix
    end if
loop
```

**I added a space between the " and the *.xlsx**, as there is always a space after the 3 digit suffix.

What I want to know is: why did that work? why did 696 match 669? It makes no sense.

Comment: Would be best to share your `fileExists` function too otherwise this is not a [reprex].

Comment: `Dir()`returns a string containing the specified file name, a null string if there is no file or directory name to return. Therefore your function `fileExists` converts the return of the Dir() function to a Boolean. That is where the error is likely to reside.